# How to prevent binding to docker0 bridge in overlay mode

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use docker with weave, and I'd like to keep interfaces in container clean. That is: I want the only attached interfaces to be weave's and localhost. Currently docker also binds its bridge.

Is it possible to attach only to overlay network in Docker?

```
$ docker run -ti --net none busybox ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
```

but

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:12:00:02
          inet addr:172.18.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe12:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:90 (90.0 B)  TX bytes:270 (270.0 B)

ethwe0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:E6:28:21:75:9A
          inet addr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::50e6:28ff:fe21:759a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:508 (508.0 B)  TX bytes:258 (258.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 2):

The network needs to be created with `-internal` flag, see:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18854